# why this method doesn't return true?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean, logic

i have the following task to do:
write a method that gets an array as a parameter and an int number.
the method returns true if there is a difference between 2 numbers in the array that its difference is bigger than the number variable value.
notice that you can loop the array only once.
so i wrote:

```
public class difference
{
    public boolean difference(int[] a, int x)
    {
        int firstNum=a[0];//3
        boolean answer=false;
        for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if (Math.abs(firstNum)-(Math.abs(a[i]))>Math.abs(x)) {
                answer=true;  
                break;  
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        difference test= new difference();
        int[] array={3,4,6};
        System.out.println(test.difference(array,0));
    }
}
```

but for some reason this prints me false instead of true
why?

Comment: Your main problem is that you use `Math.abs` on each of the numbers and not on the difference, so you're comparing with negative number. But the algorithm is wrong anyway, because you need to check difference between all numbers and not just first. The correct solution to the problem is probably finding the largest and smallest numbers in the array and their difference will be the max difference in the array.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.abs(firstNum)-(Math.abs(a[i])`

must be

`Math.abs(firstNum - a[i])`

You should get the `abs` of the difference and not each number.

But, what you are doing is `abs(3) - abs(4)` = `-1` which is less than 0. (similar thing for the others)

> [...]if there is a difference between 2 numbers in the array that its difference is bigger than the number variable value

But you are only comparing the first number with each other...

If you need to find if two numbers exist such that the difference among them is greater than the passed integer, find the min and the max and find the difference between them (Thanks to @NeplatnyUdaj for correcting me)

Comment: "you cannot do it in one pass.". Yes, he can. He just needs to find the difference between smallest and largest number.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Oops. You are right. I thought this is a two sum problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not the solution at the problem. 
There are two solutions at least, the first is O(n^2) and require to have two for loops to compare all the elements between them self.
The second solution that you should use and that the problem force you to choose because it says that you can loop the array only once, it is to find in one for loop the minimum and the maximum of the array and control their difference. If their difference is more than the given number return true otherwise false.